# Group-by using pandas and plot lines in Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have the following df, and I am trying to build 2 different plots using Plotly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'weight':[12,11,10,14,16,13,12,15,16],
                   'height':[110,111,116,111,110,113,115,114, 112],
                   'name':['Adam', 'Steve','Mike', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Steve', 'Mike','Mike','Steve'],
                   'category':[1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1]})
```

The first plot I am trying to build is to groupby the df by 'name' and plot weight versus height for each name. (see PLOT 1)
The second plot I want to build is to first groupby 'Category' then plot weight vs height for each 'name' as a subplot. If there are two categories (as in this example) then I want to have two subplots, if 3 categories then 3 subplots, and so on. (See PLOT 2)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a single call to [`px.line`](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/):

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'weight':[12,11,10,14,16,13,12,15,16],
                   'height':[110,111,116,111,110,113,115,114, 112],
                   'name':['Adam', 'Steve','Mike', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Steve', 'Mike','Mike','Steve'],
                   'category':[1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1]})

fig = px.line(df, x="weight", y="height", color='name', markers=True, facet_col="category")
fig.show()
```

Output:
[image]

You can specify how many columns will fit in a row with `facet_col_wrap=n_col` (see [doc](https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/))